# What does the phrase "That'll do it" mean? And what is the grammar behind that?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The quote is:

> — Do you have any hobbies?
> — Uh, not really. I used to sing in church choir, but then I realized I can't sing.
> — Right.
> — And I stopped believing in God.
> — **That'll do it.**
> — So... yeah.

Answer (score 2):

The sense here is agreeing with the speaker that the action will have that consequence. Namely, realising you can't sing plus stopping believing in God will have the effect of making you want to stop singing in the church choir.